# How check if file exists in shell script by ignoring case sensitivity?

Tags: bash, shell

I am passing fileName as an argument to shell script.
--fileName=abc
And my file is present as ABC in a directory.
How to check if file exists?

Comment: What is the expected outcome if there is a file named `aBc`?

Comment: Whilst it's easy to implement what you are asking, the normal expectation would be for a nonexistent file name to result in an error, not for the system to guess which file you meant.